# How to set multiple values(or list/array) as a hive variable

Tags: hive, hql

I wish to declear a list of values and store it in a variable of sorts in hive and be able to call it later. see below. does hive variable do the trick?

Plan:

```
SET hivevar:periods = (202101, 202102, 202103)
```

When Calling:

```
select 
    *
from
    table
where
    period in ${hivevar:periods}
```

shows a table with results from the specified periods.